# What is Atomicity in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I am studying JAVA concurrency in Practice and found the following definition of Atomic Operation:

> Operation A, B are atomic with respect to each other if from the perspective of thread executing A, when another thread executes B, either all of B has executed or none of it has. **An atomic operation is one that is atomic with respect to all operation, including itself, that operates on the same data**.

Lets say I have two thread A & B both accessing AtomicLong variable count.
Lets say thread A reads count and thread B was busy doing count.incrementAndGe() operation.
In such a scenario, As per above definition (either all of B has executed or none of it ):

A) ThreadA see the previous value of count (because count is not yet updated)

Or

B) ThreadA will wait until ThreadB completes the operation and see the latest value.

As per my understanding it should B because otherwise we still could have race condition.

Comment: It won't wait.  Depending on the precise timing, the thread A will see either the value before thread B increments it or after it increments.  You cannot predict which.  But one guarantee of atomicity is that thread A won't see some strange intermediate state.  (A second guarantee is that if two threads perform increments simultaneously, both will be performed correctly ... in some order.  No "counts" will be lost, no extra ones added.)

Comment: @StephenC That means if I am doing count.incrementAndGet() in my method that is being executed by multiple threads, I could still have race condition right. Because both threads A and B could read the same value and one of them will overwrite the another one. Effectively I will end up with one increment instead of 2.

Comment: No.  You won't.  See my update to my previous comment.   But the result of one or other of the incrementAndGet calls won't include both of the increments.

Comment: FYI… See Wikipedia: [*Linearizability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability), and on a related note, [*Atomicity (database systems)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation you have described is called a "data race." Either thread A will win the race (it sees the initial value), or thread B will win the race (thread A sees the final value.) Unless you have provided some explicit means to force the threads to access the variable in a particular order, then there is no way to know who will win the race.

---

"Atomicity" means that thread B will either see the data as it was before the atomic operation, or it will see it after the operation is complete. Thread B can never see it in a half-way-done state.

For an update to a single, 64-bit `long` value. Pretty much the only way it could be "half-way-done" is if the 64-bit value were *torn* on 32-bit hardware. It would be "torn" if one of the two 32-bit words comprising the 64-bit value had been updated, and the other had not.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your answer. But I am unable to relate this definition with how I am able to do correct increment with AtomicLong or AtomicInt variable. Lets say ThreadA and ThreadB both doing getAndIncrement, It should be possible for threadB to see the previous value while threadA is busy doing increment - which means number of increments  will be lost.

Comment: @Tarun, In the case where both threads are doing an atomic `getAndIncrement()`, the atomicity works both ways. If thread A wins the race, then thread B will not access the variable until thread A has finished the entire operation (i.e., until thread A has posted the incremented value.) If thread B wins the race, then thread A will not access the variable until B is finished. The value returned to the winner will be the original value, The value returned to the loser will be original+1, and the final count will be original+2. Always.

Comment: One Question, When you say "Wins the race", Do you mean whoever read the value first in getAndInrement Context ?

Comment: Thanks. It makes complete sense now. "Wins the race" means whoever first executed the operation.

Comment: @Tarun, Yes. If thread A "reads the value first," then thread A must write back the incremented value before thread B will be allowed to read it, and vice versa. The entire `getAndIncrement()` function call happens atomically: When some thread T is doing it, there literally is _no identifiable point in time_ in any other thread that comes between when T started and when T finished.

Comment: Small correction: it isn't a data race, but a race condition. Data races happen when you have conflicting actions that are not ordered by a happens-before edge. Volatile reads/writes are synchronization operations and excluded from data races.